# Maximum file size for iFrame in IE7

Tags: php, iframe, download, headers, internet-explorer-7

I've got a "super secure" javascript downloader<sup>*</sup> that I wrote, and it usually works alright. But I noticed, while trying to download a 90 meg file with it on a client's machine that on IE7, it's getting hung up about 1/3rd of the way through.  I've never tried to send a file that large through the iFrame and it works fine in other browsers.  Is there a size restriction on files that IE7 can read in an iFrame?

<sup>* It's really just a PHP line that sets header("location: http://someplace/downloadbigthing.exe"); after it does some logging and verification.</sup>

Comment: I very much doubt it's IE7, it could be the ISP choking a big download - have you been able to replicate the problem on different connections?

Comment: Well, I downloaded the file (on their computer) by putting in the URL directly and not pumping it through the IFrame.

Comment: I would try it on a different connection - the more the better, just to be sure the problem can be replicated.

Comment: Probably a good idea, but I'm probably just going to have to wait for someone to call with the same problem.  A few hundred people have already downloaded this file, I guess I could check the log to see if any used IE7.

Comment: May also want to look at the PHP output buffering controls if it's writing anything out along the way... http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

IE7 is nearly a full decade old. Time to end support for it IMHO. Do a check and if IE <= 7 just display upgrade message and link to manual instructions if that won't work. Done.